# silverlight4 tools for visual studio 2010 fails with the following error... HELP!

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, migration

I am trying to migrate my silverlight applications from version 3 to version 4. I've been running into this problem. when i try to install silverlight4 tools for visual studio 2010

> Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer Express 2010 or Visual Phone Developer Express 2010 that matches the language version of Silverlight Tools 4 must be installed before installation of Silverlight Tools can continue.  Silverlight Tools is available in other languages at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177432.

I have installed

> microsoft visual studio 2010 professional
>   version 10.0.30319.1.RTMRel
>
> Microsoft .net framework
>   version 4.0.30319 RTMRel

please help!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight tools 4 is available in English, French, German and Japanese.  You need to have downloaded the correct language version of the [Silverlight Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=eff8a0da-0a4d-48e8-8366-6ddf2ecad801) (note the language combobox).

If your version of Studio is installed for another language then you could try installing the English Visual Web Developer Express 2010 (it should install fine side-by-side with your standard product) then installing the Tools.  I'm not sure that will get you completely to where you'd want to be as far as templates are concerned but it should get you going.

Comment: I have the english version of VS2010 and am trying the english version of sivlerlight tools. Still it does give me the same error.
I think my visual studio verion 10.0.30319.1.RTMRel is the final correct version.

Answer (score 1):

**How to determine what failed**

If you use the Web Platform Installer to install, it tells you in the log file what happened.

```
IronSpigot::Main::LogPackageNameAndVersion(): Package Name = Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010
IronSpigot::Main::LogPackageNameAndVersion(): Package Version = 10.0.30319 1033
```

It will compare these against the values in the following two registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Setup\VS\BuildNumber\1033
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\General\UILanguage
```

If you have VS.NET 2010 SP1 for en-us, the first will contain '10.0.40219' and the second 1033.

The setup confusingly reports this as a language issue, but if you read carefully it is a language and version issue.

**Here's how to work around the version check:**

1. Using regedit, change the first key to 10.0.30319. Run the setup.
2. Using regedit, change the first key back to 10.0.40219
3. I recommend reapplying SP1 to be safe, but I'm not sure if it is required.

This other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402774/cannot-install-silverlight-4-tools-on-visual-studio-2010-sp1) has a longer solution which is to uninstall SP1, install the tools, then reinstall SP1.

Comment: Interestingly, I don't have the Setup key in my HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE tree. I do have the UI language key, but it's properly set. I like this solution (I've never had any real problems editing the registry) because it is simple, quick, and straight forward. But, I'm loathe to add a key that's not even there.

Answer (score 0):

coudn't find the soulution.

however my issue resolved when i installed the same build version of Visual Studio Premium version.