# Error When Installing Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm in the process of migrating from my old 32-bit Windows XP development machine to a new one that's running 64-bit Windows 7. I have the same stuff (VS 2010 + Silverlight Tools 4) installed and working on my old development machine.

I get a build error on my new development machine in VS 2010 when trying to build my F# Silverlight 4 project:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets(138,9): error : F# runtime for Silverlight version v4.0 is not installed. Please go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177463 to download and install matching F# runtime
Done building project "FCBuySideSilverlight.fsproj" -- FAILED.
```

I follow the link provided in the error, and download MS Silverlight Tools 4: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177463
However, when I try to it, I get this strange error:

[image: MS Silverlight Tools 4 Language Error]

All of my installations are in the English language, so it's very strange. What's more is that the link they provide (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=177432) doesn't actually go anywhere useful.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: VS SP1 has pre-installed silverlight tools. Just update IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to install the WebPI application tool + Visual Web Developer Express (here: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/). I could then install Silverlight Tools 4 through the WebPI installer. I also installed Visual Studio 2010 SP1 using WebPI, so that may have also done it (as @vorrtex suggested in the comment above).

Comment: I was having exactly the same problem, and this worked for me as well... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This previous StackOverflow question explains it: [Cannot install silverlight 4 tools on visual studio 2010 sp1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402774/cannot-install-silverlight-4-tools-on-visual-studio-2010-sp1)

Basically, it is now provided with SP1 assuming you have installed the Web Developer Tools.

You shouldn't use WebPI (in this case) cause that will just download far too much shit (like VS2010 *Express* (W-T-F!!!!!!!!!!!!!!) + more bloat :(