# Can't install silverlight 4 tools on Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-toolkit

I'm blocked by the requirements even though I fulfill everyone. I had almost the same issue as the referenced here:
[Cannot install silverlight 4 tools on visual studio 2010 sp1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402774/cannot-install-silverlight-4-tools-on-visual-studio-2010-sp1)
The difference is that the solution did not work for me and I already did have Visual Web Developer installed.

I tried a complete re-install of VS 2010 and then installed SP1 which should have installed Silverlight4_Tools for me but references to System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit did not work and nothing was added under "...Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0". All I see when I look at all the .Net references available are the SL4 library references. For instance, I see "..\Client\System.Windows.Controls.Input.dll" but not "..\Client\System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit.dll" and everything is labeled as version 2.0.5.0 with Runtime V2.0.50727 - which is a .Net 2 framework version and seems strange. The .Web project shows .Net 4 framework on project properties and the SL project show Silverlight 4 (in case anyone is wondering).

Any suggestions of what to try?

Comment: how did you manage to solve this issue. I am running into same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an old question, but it just happened to me although I had installed the Visual Web Devoleper feature.

I had to uninstall SP1 first, and also uninstall Silverlight 4 Tools, if you don't uninstall the Tools, the new installation silently fails (better if you uninstall everything related to Silverlight 4).

Then install SP1 again, and every piece of software that goes on SP1 (as for example, Async CTP).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010 is included in Visual Studio 2010 SP1
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/326e7368-d071-4588-bba8-8591be3c9e39
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509