# VS 2010 SP1 Forcing Silverlight Upgrade

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

On our developer machines, we have Silverlight 4 installed.  We upgraded to VS 2010 SP1, and now our Silverlight projects won't open; it is prompting us that we need to install the newer version of Silverlight, and takes us to a link to download Silverlight 5.

We are not ready to go to Silverlight 5 yet, and need to be able to open up our Silverlight 4 projects in VS 2010 SP1.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402774/cannot-install-silverlight-4-tools-on-visual-studio-2010-sp1), but since you say you had Silverlight 4 installed before it may not be.

I recently rebuild my development machine and ran into a similar problem, but closer to that other question. Ultimately, I found this [blog post](http://brianseekford.com/index.php/2010/07/01/silverlight-developer-runtime-not-installed-silverlight-4/), which led me to a installer for [Silverlight 4 Developer Runtime](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039).

There was one issue the author mentioned, that I have not run into yet:

> I have noticed a large number of people hitting this page. Well,
>   let me help you guys out a little more. It turns out that EVERY time
>   Microsoft decides to update the Silverlight runtime. A patch, string
>   change, someone looked at it wrong, the Developer runtime gets
>   invalidated.
>
> You will need to reinstall it each time. So make sure you keep it
>   handy! Thanks Microsoft for such a wonder feature. I love reinstalling
>   things every week.

EDIT:

I ran into the issue mentioned above and reinstalling the Silverlight 4 Developer Runtime did not fix the issue for me. I ended up installing the Silverlight 5 Developer Runtime ([32 bit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229323), [64 bit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229324)), which I obtained from this [page](http://www.silverlight.net/downloads), and that fixed the issue.

Comment: That was it; I had to reinstall the "Developer" Runtime for Silverlight 4. I am not sure why upgrading to SP1 required me to reinstall the "Developer eddition, but oh well, I am just happy it was an easy fix. Thanks for your prompt reply.