# Silverlight not working with VS10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, silverlight

I am using VS10 Ultimate and I have tried every download of Silverlight possible, but whenever I want to create a Silverlight application, VS wont even create the project. My problem is very similar to the question asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402774/cannot-install-silverlight-4-tools-on-visual-studio-2010-sp1#comment20968211_13895251) but none of those answers are seeming to work for me. I am getting extremely frustrated with this and I hope someone knows how to fix this because I've been looking for an answer for the past hour and a half with no avail.

Comment: Could you add some error messages (e.g. from Visual Studio) you get?

Comment: @Jozef Benikovský I get a box when trying to create an application that says "You need to install the latest Silverlight Developer runtime before creating a Silverlight project. Download runtime at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=146060" even though it is already downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I fixed it. What I had to do was completely reinstall both Silverlight (all versions, even one version still installed wouldn't work for me) and also Visual Studio (including the service packs) using windows uninstaller. It took some time (as VS is quite a large file to download) but now everything works like a charm!

Download Silverlight [HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/Get-Started/Install/Default.aspx)

Download Silverlight Dev Tools [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight/bb187358.aspx)

Download Visual Studio [HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio)